# Is there a way to find out how many distinct roots a polynomial has?

Tags: polynomials

Let say we have an arbitrary polynomial over the reals, and we do not know whether it is separable or not. Is there some algorithm to find the number of roots it has in the complex number?

Comment: This question has answers in textbooks on field theory as one of the results. Not ideal for Mathoverflow; better to be in math.stackexchange.

Comment: okay, I apologize for that

Comment: So should I delete this question or what?

Comment: Welcome to MO. No, let's let the question stand. Just for future reference: we also would like to ask users to supply context and motivation for their questions, where possible: this also helps the community to determine suitability for MO (e.g. some questions that may initially look like "not research level" actually do arise within a research context).

Comment: Yeah, although this question was elementary compared to research-level mathematicians, it still managed to keep my mind busy for a few hours so I decided for this to be my first question. I'll switch to Stackexchange now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $f(z) = \prod (z-z_i)^{n_i}$, with $z_i$ distinct, then $GCD(f(z), f'(z)) = \prod (z-z_i)^{n_i-1}$, so the number of distinct complex roots is $\deg f - \deg GCD(f, f')$. If $f$ has rational coefficients, or in some other sense can be computed with exactly, this is a practical method; polynomial GCD can be computed by the Euclidean algorithm. If the coefficients of $f$ are only known approximately, then you need to think about what you mean by number of roots, since perturbing $x^2$ (one root) can give $x^2-\epsilon$ (two roots).

Also, if you meant to ask how many real roots there are, see [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. The key is the square-free factorization which is an algorithm for factoring a polynomial $f$ into
 $f=f_1^{e^1}\cdots f_r^{e_r}$, where all the $f_i$ are square free.
In your case, the number of complex roots would then be the degree of $f_1\cdots f_r$.
Look for example in *von zur Gathen, J.  and Gerhard, J. Modern Computer Algebra. Cambridge, England: Cambridge University Press, pp. 601-606, 1999.*